# Issue with ngbTooltip after upgrading Angular and ng-bootstrap versions

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4naW.png)Hello everyone,

I recently upgraded my Angular project from version 12 to version 15. As part of the upgrade, I also updated my ng-bootstrap library to version 15.0.1. However, after the update, I started encountering errors with the ngbTooltip .

Here are the details of the issue:

1. Angular version: 15
2. ng-bootstrap version: 15.0.1
3. Error message: Can't bind to ngbTooltip since its not a known property of a
   Error came after upgrading from angular 12 to 15,ngbootstrap9.3.1 to ngbootstrap@15.0.1
   I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on what might be causing this issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it.
   You will find the picture of same attached

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.